# Is there any sample of ASP.NET Core OData API with EF Core what supports geometry queries?

Tags: asp.net-core, geometry, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I know how to create with a few lines ASP.NET Core OData API over an EF Core model. I've also aware that there is geometry support for EF by NetTopologySuite.

I am looking OData geometry query support, *hopefully a working sample app*, or demo code. Any hints?

**What I've tried so far:**

- Googling: I found only "text" about MS OData geometry support, not in context of EF, and no code.
- Github: looked for repos with keywords [OData Geometry Core]: nothing, then just for [OData Geometry]: ditto. (I found OData.OData but not as repo, just as source, but not this is what I am looking for)

Am I too early with this?

Comment: There is an opened bug, that reading spatial data might not work in EF Core at the moment, https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1792